# PHP, How to scrape the content of an iframe?

Tags: php, web, web-scraping

I use php simple dom to do some scrapping,

But currently i'm hitting the rock as the web page is using an iframe,

I cannot parse the content of the iframe directly with php simple dom (it dont find anything from the iframe content),

And when I try to access the "src" value of that iframe, It seems that "src" of that iframe allow access only from that particular website ip (i cannot copy-paste the src value to another web browser and get the content, if I try to do that it will only return blank screen),

My question is how to overcome this?

Is this do-able using PHP and php simple dom?

Or should I use different PHP library or even different language (not PHP)?

Comment: looks like they dont want you stealing there data

Comment: An IFRAME is loaded using a separate HTTP request. The content of the IFRAME document is not a part of the wrapping document. You have to make a separate HTTP call to fetch the content of the IFRAME.

Comment: @nogad, come on.. dont you feel challenged? :)

Comment: @galchen, yes I am aware of that, thats why I ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to access the "src" value of that iframe, it [..] allows access only from that particular website ip

Nope, that's not how that works. *Your browser* is fetching the iframe's `src`, not "the website". The access must be allowed for all possible IPs, otherwise no regular user would be able to see the contents of that URL.

What is more likely is that the server is checking the *referer URL*. When your browser requests the iframe's `src`, it also sends an [HTTP header `Referer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) with the URL of the page where the `iframe` was embedded in. The web server may reject requests unless they came from a particular referer.

Fortunately it's just an HTTP header, which you can set yourself when you fetch the iframe's `src`. Additionally, inspect the complete HTTP request for the iframe's `src` in your browser and possibly include any additional headers you may see. If you replicate the exact HTTP request you see in the browser, you must be able to fetch the contents; no web server is able to distinguish two identical HTTP requests.

Comment: Thank you, this is what Im searching for!

Answer (score 1):

When you go into the website - your browser makes the HTTP request (not the server), so you should have no problem making an HTTP request to fetch the content of the iframe. Try to use `view-source` instead of displaying the iframe url in a browser (maybe it's protected with javascript).

Another possibility is that they are using a token or a cookie that expires after your browser fetches the iframe for the first time, so you cannot access it again. If the token/cookie is generated with the first request (of the wrapping page) then you should be able to add the parameters to the HTTP request for the iframe. Otherwise (if it is generated with ajax for example) then you will need to imitate the ajax call (with another HTTP request).

I would suggest using node.js and not PHP for scraping, since you can run an entire webkit on your machine and fetch the content as a browser (run JS etc).